# query large table

Tags: t-sql

Is it better to query large table (> 1.5 million rows) 3 times or to put 3 condition in the same query? The sample `where` clause is below. There are similar or more complicated `where` clauses. My hunch is to put all of them in same `where`. But need some input from community. Thanks in advance.

```
where (a =1 or b=1) and (a=2 or b=3) and (c=1 or d=3)
```

Comment: Your logic might be inverted with respect to AND and OR - could you check?

Comment: Just run the queries and see for yourself

Comment: Thanks all of you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single trip to the database is definitely preferable. Make sure you index the `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` columns and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your schema (datatypes, keys, indicies etc), generally speaking I'd say you would be better off adding all the conditions to the same where clause so the query optimizer has as much information as possible to work with. The best way to find out is to run some tests to see which approach yields the best performance on your data/schema.

Answer (score 1):

**Put it all in one query.**

In addition to reduced overhead, you will eliminate duplicates this way.  If you have a row that matches more than one of your criteria, it will appear twice in your final result set if you query multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It's quicker to put them all in the same `where` clause, generally. However, each query is different, and make sure you check the query plans for each query to ensure you're getting the best performance out of them you can be.