# optimize SP on sql server 2k5

Tags: t-sql

I asked a question [query large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883355/query-large-table/8884270#8884270). This is in response to the same question. There are 4 columns in the `where` clause. I replaced the cursor with the `while` loop. But didn't help much. The difference between old and new code is 1 second only. But one thing I noticed. There is one column `[col name] varchar(255) allow nulls`. If I don't query that column the execution time of new code is half. What can be done to improve the speed? All the columns in the `where` clause are indexed. Any help is appreciated.

while' loop is sample code.

```
declare @temp table (col1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
            col2 VARCHAR(10),
            col3 VARCHAR(40),
            col4 VARCHAR(40)    )
INSERT INTO @temp (col1,col2,col3,col4)              
SELECT col1,col2,SUBSTRING(col3,1,40),col4 
FROM dbo.Clients WHERE col5 <> 4
ORDER BY col1
select @from=1,@to=@@rowcout
SELECT TOP 1 @col1 = col1,@col2=col2,@col3=col3,@col4=col4 FROM @Temp ORDER BY col1
while @from <= @to
begin
    insert into table2 (....) select ... from table3 where [col name1] = par1 and ([col name2] =par2 or [col name2] = par3] )
    --this one takes time
    insert into table2 (...)  select .. from table3 where [col name] like @par1 AND ([col name] like par2 or [col name] like par3)
SELECT TOP 1 @col1 = col1,@col2=col2,@col3=col3,@col4=col4 FROM @Temp where col1 > @col1 ORDER BY col1
set @from = @from + 1
end
```

Comment: You nee to show the **actual** table structure and **actual** query to get an actual **answer.**

Comment: You are doing 3 `LIKE` comparisons, against the same column?

Comment: Yes. 3 LIKE. is this the reason?

Comment: Do you do a string check as in `column LIKE '%stuff%'`?

Comment: OK, you need to show the whole query. It's very likely you can eliminate the loop altogether.

Comment: Unless either par2 or par3 are equal to par1 there will be no return rows because of the AND condition, so why dont u change the logic to where [col name] IN (par2, par3)?

Comment: The reason you are having performance issues si that you are doing rowby row processing which is exceedly slow. I told you how to fix it if you read teh link I provided. YOu need to commit yourself to never using a lop again or a cursor until you know when to use them. They are slow and are techniques of last resort not first resort!

Answer (score 3):

Cursors and while loops are equally bad ideas. There's about a 90+% chance you don't need either. IfF you have a lot of records, table varaibles tend to be on the slow side as well. Use temp tables instead(although from what you put into the table variable, I suspect you don't need that either).

This link may be of use:

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

To get a detailed explanation of how to improve what you are doign you have to show us what you are doing, you deleted the most critical part for answering the question.

Comment: +1 for `you deleted the most critical part for answering the question.` - We know how variable declarations and while loops work!  What we don't know is what's in his/her code.

Comment: i tried the temp table, but didn't help. As far as code is concerned, what else do you need? I put the statement that takes most time. Beside that there are 2 more similar statements in the while loop.

Comment: YOu need to stop thinking of processing records one at a time. There is nothing inteh statment you gave which requires a while loop. Please read the link for examples of how to do this in a set based fashion.